# Why am I getting duplicate items from MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I am using an Ajax call to a PHP file to get data from MySQL database and populate select options in HTML. The problem is that duplicate items in the options and I don't know why. I tried the query in workbench and it brings back what I need.

PHP file:

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET["q"];

   // open db connection code

   $query = "select * from r2rtool.materialtype where type = 'FE' and tools like '%".$q."%'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   $option = "";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $mat = $row["Material"];
        $option.="<option value=\"$mat\">".$mat."</option>";

        echo $option;
    }

   // close db connection
?>
```

Ajax function:

```
function populatematerial(str)
{
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else{
      // IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","phpfile.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $option .= "<option value=\"{$row[Material]}\">{$row[Material]}</option>";
}
echo $option;
```

Comment: In other words, do your output AFTER you finish retrieving/building the data. Your version is building, outputting, adding a bit more, outputting again, etc...

Comment: It is not exactly duplicate, you are getting something like 1 12 123 1234 12345...

Comment: I love you. Worked perfect. :-D

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to move the `echo $option;` out of the while loop, like so:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $mat = $row["Material"];
    $option.="<option value=\"$mat\">".$mat."</option>";
}
echo $option;
```

You should output the HTML after you built it, not while you build it.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` because array returns value in numbers and name both format, so it will twice data,

where `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns array as only name element of array ..

for more understanding 
try

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("some query ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($row);
$assoc = mysql_fetch_array($row);
print_r ($row);
echo "<br>";
print_r ($assoc);
echo "<br>";
?>
```